# Implementation of a pure virtual function in C++

Tags: c++, virtual

Given the following scenario, I have a base class `MyBaseClass` with a pure virtual function `void foo() = 0;` . Two classes `MyClassA` and `MyClassB` are derived from that class `MyBaseClass`. Both implement the function `foo()`. 
Now in a project I work on, I came across an object created from class `MyBaseClass` on which the function `foo()` is called. 
Interestingly, it's the implementation from `MyClassB` that is used.
Where is defined that it's this implementation and not the one from `MyClassA`

Comment: If `MyBaseClass` has a pure virtual function, how can it be instantiated?

Answer (score 4):

The object was of type `MyClassB` not `MyBaseClass`.  `MyBaseClass` is abstract and cannot be instantiated.  However you probably had a pointer `MyBaseClass*` which was pointing to an instance of `MyClassB`.

You should probably read up on inheritance and polymorphism in C++ if you need some more information.

```
MyBaseClass base; // Compiler error, cannot instantiate abstract class
MyClassA a;
MyClassB b;

MyBaseClass* pA = &a;
MyBaseClass* pB = &b;

pA->foo(); // Uses implementation of foo in MyClassA
pB->foo(); // Uses implementation of foo in MyClassB
```

Comment: You were right. It was a pointer of `MyBaseClass` I thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Is there a way of calling the implementation of `MyClassA` although `pA` is pointing to an object of class `MyClassB`? Maybe with a cast?

Comment: No, not in any way that is safe.  `MyClassA` and `MyClassB` are different types.  If you are trying to have common methods between the two classes then you could implement it in the base class.

Comment: If I implement the method in the base class, will this be the implementation that is called no matter of what type the object will be that the baseClass pointer points to?

Comment: Yes, unless the method is virtual in which case you can override it in derived classes.  Dervied classes that do not override the method will use the implementation in the base class.

Answer (score 3):

> I came across an object created from class MyBaseClass

No, you did not. Objects of type `MyBaseClass` can't exist. The class is abstract and cannot be instantiated.

You likely came about a *pointer* to a `MyBaseClass`, which can point to any objects of classes that inherit the base class.

> Is there a way of calling the implementation of MyClassA although pA is pointing to an object of class MyClassB? Maybe with a cast?

You can call

```
pA->MyBaseClass::foo();
```

but this will only work if the function is implemented. (yes, you can provide an implementation for pure method)

Comment: Thanks, it indeed is a pointer and not an object of the base class! Is there a way of calling the implementation of `MyClassA` although `pA` is pointing to an object of class `MyClassB`? Maybe with a cast?

Answer (score 1):

It is important to notice the difference between these snippets:

```
struct X
{
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

X x; // not valid! X has purely virtual methods
```

and

```
struct X; // as above
struct Y : X
{
    void foo() {}
    void bar() {}
};

X * x = new Y; // valid!
```

The second case is most likely what you have seen. In this pattern you can call `x->foo();` and it will call `Y::foo()`. Note that you cannot, however, call `x->bar()` because `X::bar()` does not exist.